# insert below the header in gridview and not in the footer?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

using asp.net/sqldatasource/vb

Is there a way to place the insert row below the header in a gridview instead of in the footer?

Answer (score 0):

No. Not that I'm aware of anyway.

You'd need to create a custom control which inhertis from the GridView class and override one of the Render methods. Or just write your own control.

A simplier method though, would be to hide the GridView header, create a html table that is the same style as the GridView header with a insert row below and then just place it directly above your GridView. Cheating in a way - but it'll work as long as you have all the columns at the same width in your GridView and your html table.

Comment: Thought about the second method. Do you mean put the insert row in the header template instead of the footer?

Comment: You could try that. Never done it myself. What I meant was create your own header and insert row using standard Html and put it above your GridView (outside the GridView). Just make it the same style as your GridView (i.e. same background colour, font colour, cell widths etc.). Then turn ShowHeader to false, as you have created you own.